# Smooth Scrolling jumps weirdly

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

```
$(function() {$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    if (target.length <= 1000) {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 60
      }, 1000);
    };
    return false;
  }
}});});
```

I’m working with a nav bar that becomes fixed with a screen max-width < 1000px.
 The height of the navigation bar is 60px. So it goes backwards with animation 60px if max-with < 1000px.

All this works fine, but my problem is that the page jumps weirdly only when the viewport is bigger than 1000px.

Comment: i don't see any jumping on the site (viewport 1440px)

Comment: Neither do I: 2560 px width

Comment: @DavidBucka Is a really short flash try it a couple of times and you will see it

Comment: @JonasGrumann click on 1.1 a couple of times and you will see it is a short flash

Comment: I see it now try preventing the default event: $("selector").click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();
/* your code */
})

Comment: Don't worry I got it ;)

Comment: Also, for future posts, try creating a fiddle on https://jsfiddle.net/ or recreate the isolated problem here on stackoverflow. That way, future users who might have the same issue can see an exact example of the problem. What happens if you remove your website or make a new one? Your link in the question will be invalid, resulting broken question.

Comment: @JonasGrumann I will do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're not preventing the default click event. This means that the browser jumps to the #id you want (as this is default browser behavior) and then the smooth scroll kicks in a triggers the animation from the beginning, resulting in a quick jump.

to fix it just block the default event with `preventDefault();`

Quick example:

```
$('selector').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code
});
```

Fixed code:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault(); {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 1000px)').matches) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 60
                    }, 1000);

                    window.location.hash = '#' + target[0].id;

                    return false;
                }
              }
            }
          }
    });
});
```